# Rolling a random walk on a sphere

Tags: random-walks, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry

A ball rolls down an inclined plane, encountering horizontal obstacles, at which it
rolls left/right with equal probability. There are regularly spaced staggered gaps that let the ball
roll down to the next, lower obstacle. The pattern resembles a binary tree:

[image: Rolling Obstacles]
Suppose the vertical and horizontal rolls have equal length $\delta$.
Tracing out the roll contact point on the ball surface we see a random walk, with each step a
geodesic arc of length $\delta$, and $90^\circ$ turns.
I expected that for rational (multiples of $\pi$) $\delta$, the trace would not fill the surface,
but the experiment below for $\delta=\pi/16$ (for 10, $10^2$, $10^3$, $10^4$ downhill steps)
indicates otherwise.

> For which $\delta$ will this trace fill the sphere surface?

[image: Sphere Paths]

Thanks for any insights!

**Answer**: The surface will be filled for every $\delta$ except $\pi/2$ and $\pi$.  See Scott Carnahan's answer below,
and Dylan Thurston's simplification.  I find this answer remarkable!

Comment: There was a related problem about the density of a group generated by two spherical rotations, both of  angular measure pi/8.  I thought the group was finite, but turned out not to be.  I suspect Bill Thurston's answer there may be relevant here.  If I recall the link I will post it.  Gerhard "Too Many Comments To Remember" Paseman, 2011.04.30

Comment: Here it is: "Maneuvering with limited moves on $S^2$, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62156 . You are right, Gerhard, it does seem related...

Comment: Given that the finite subgroups of $SO(3)$ follow the ADE classification, it shouldn't be too surprising that you are restricted to a very small class of admissible rotations.

Comment: I would just like to take this opportunity to say I absolutely love your questions.

Comment: @BB: I am truly honored! :-)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos \delta & -\sin \delta & 0 \\ \sin \delta & \cos \delta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, and let $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos \delta & -\sin \delta \\ 0 & \sin \delta & \cos \delta \end{pmatrix}$ be rotation by $\delta$ along the $z$ and $x$ axes, respectively.  In suitable coordinates, a progression down one step in the tree is either $AB$ or $AB^{-1}$.

The trace will fill (a.s.) a dense subset of the surface if and only if the closure of the group generated by $AB$ and $AB^{-1}$ is not a subgroup of $SO(3)$ of dimension zero or one.

The dimension zero closed subgroups of $SO(3)$ are either cyclic, dihedral, or symmetries of Platonic solids, and the dimension one closed subgroups are conjugates of $SO(2)$ and $O(2)$.  Therefore, it suffices to determine which values of $\delta$ yield a pair of elements in either a conjugate of $O(2)$, or a conjugate of one of the three Platonic groups (isomorphic to $A_4$, $S_4$, and $A_5$).

In order for $AB$ and $AB^{-1}$ to both lie in a conjugate of $O(2)$ it is necessary and sufficient that they have a common eigenvector with eigenvalue $\pm 1$ - this eigenvector is the axis of rotation.  Writing this requirement explicitly yields a polynomial identity in $\sin \delta$ and $\cos \delta$ <strike>(whose solutions I haven't enumerated yet)</strike>. **Edit:** Some straightforward case elimination with the $z$ coordinate of a common eigenvector shows that $\delta$ must be an integer multiple of $\pi/2$.

For the Platonic solutions, we can narrow down the solution set using the criterion that the rotation $(AB^{-1})^{-1}(AB) = B^2$ lies in the group, and Platonic solids have rotational symmetries of order at most 5.  This means $\delta$ is a multiple of $\pi/3$, $\pi/4$ or $\pi/5$.

Since the traces of $AB$ and $AB^{-1}$ are both $(\cos \delta)(2 + \cos \delta)$, we can compare with character table entries to see if that number is the trace of an element in a Platonic group.  It was pretty easy to eliminate candidates by eyeball in SAGE.

**Conclusion:** The only values of $\delta$ where the image is not dense are $0$, $\pm \pi/2$, and $\pi$.

Comment: Beautifully clear reasoning, and a remarkable conclusion!

Comment: You can make the calculations slightly easier by cutting the step size in two. Let A be the matrix you wrote down, and let C by rotation by π/2 around the y axis. Then you can alternately take the steps to be AC and AC−1. The trace of AC is then just $cos\delta$. If we have a Platonic solid group, this must be 1+2cosα for α∈{±2π/3,±π/2,±2π/5,±4pi/5}. (Every element in a Platonic group is a rotation by one of these angles.) 2δ is also in this set, and it's easy to find the solutions by hand, using $\cos\delta=(\cos\alpha-1)/2$.